# Div ID and Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a livechat script.  The livechat on my sandbox site is fixed to the bottom right of the site and scrolls with the window, but on my live site (the one this specific code is from) it is attached to the footer.

The only code I'm using on my sandbox is the script and div ID (top and bottom, not middle).

Here is what I am using on my live site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var c = document.createElement('script');
    c.type = 'text/javascript'; c.async = true;
    c.src = "http://northamericahvac.smartertrack.com/ChatLink.ashx?config=0&id=stlivechat0";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
  })();
</script>
<style>
  div.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  }
</style>
<div class="fixed">
  <div id="stlivechat0"></div>
</div>​
```

The rest I have added to try to format the livechat button.  I want it to be fixed to the bottom right so that it scrolls and isn't stuck in the bottom right.

I read that you can create a div class to format stuff included in the class, but it doesn't seem to extend to the div id.  Does the div id already have formatting and is overriding div class?

I created the little `#73AD21` bar to see if it would stay fixed, and not even that does.

Comment: Have you tried not being specific in your style tag?  That way the div styles apply to all divs.  Otherwise, you'd need to add id/stlivechat0 to that logic.

Comment: Is this the order in which you have your HTML? Because your script is likely running before your `div` even exists on the page. I'd be surprised if there aren't errors in your console...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your problem is not CSS related. The script errors because wrapping any JavaScript code into

```
<script>
  ( javascript code here )()
</script>
```

means: *"treat this code as a function and run it the very moment you process it!"*

Which means it is run *before* the `<div>` (placed below it) was added to the page. Which means it won't find a DOM element with `id="stlivechat0"` (it's inside the link).

Most likely, you were **advised** to place this `<script>` tag *just before the ending `</body>` tag* (or at least after the `<div>` with `id="stlivechat0"`). But you don't really have to: its authors wanted to prevent this type of problems. In fact, you can always place the code in a named function and call this function by its name later.

The typical time to run such a function is the `window.onload` event (when all resources loaded). Another good such moment is `document.ready` (when all the DOM was built - beware not all scripts can be run on `document.ready` - not all resources are loaded, including scripts, stylesheets, images or media.

However, in your case, the simplest solution is just to place the `<script>` tag after the `<div>`:

```html
<style>
  div.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  }
</style>
<div class="fixed">
  <div id="stlivechat0"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  ({
    var c = document.createElement('script');
    c.type = 'text/javascript'; c.async = true;
    c.src = "http://northamericahvac.smartertrack.com/ChatLink.ashx?config=0&id=stlivechat0";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
  })();
</script>
```

**Do note** your script can't run on StackOverflow (it's blocked, as it's not served over `https://`).

But, as you can see, the CSS applies.

---

As Sebastian noted in the comment below, an equivalent of placing your script on `window.onload` event is adding the `defer` attribute to it: `<script src="..." defer>`. It's supported by [above 95%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer) of currently used browsers.

Comment: I think adding the `defer` attribute to your style element like `<script type="text/javascript">` could solve the problem too, by deferring the script execution until the page is completely loaded

Comment: I added your remark to the answer. Thank you, @Sebastian.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I went ahead and replaced my janky code with yours, but now nothing shows.  I am wondering if there is interference somewhere else in the site.  On the sandbox I was able to just paste what I have (minus the style) at the bottom of the footer. ):

Comment: Here's the website just so you can see.  I have the original code in there.  If I use yours it shows the green bar but not the livechat button.  http://www.usahvacsupply.com/ (I did NOT design this.)

Comment: @Heather, I played around with so many versions of "your" code that I got it to a non-working state. It ended up being placed in a function that's never called. It needs to be called. Either on the spot (as before, because now the `<div>` exists in DOM, or on `window.onload`. I updated the example.